# Flutter Cant convert 00.00 to seconds , inSeconds() method shows error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am tryna make a audio player but having trouble seeking the slider to the current duration of the song,
thank you,

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
player.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((Duration duration) {
  setState(() {
    currenttime = duration;
  });
});
player.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration duration) {
  setState(() {
    totaltime = duration;
  });
});
}
```

this the slider widget that catches the CURRENTTIME AND TOTALTIME .

```
Slider(
                        value: currenttime.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                        max: totaltime.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                        min: 0.0,
                        activeColor: mycolor,
                        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                        onChanged: (double value) {
                          setState(() {
                            int second = value.toInt();
                            Duration seeked = Duration(seconds: second);
                            player.seek(seeked);
                            value = value;
                          });
                        }),
```

And this is the Error

```
═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#8e9ee):
The getter 'inSeconds' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: inSeconds
```

Comment: Looks like it's null try debugging the value and you'll know

Comment: @OMiShah how to debug? sorry if that was stupid.

Comment: I meant, try to print the value of that variable. Most probably you're trying to convert a null variable before it's even initialised which is causing the issue

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary operator as `currenttime` seems to be null initially or investigate why it is coming null.

```
Slider(
       value: currenttime != null? currenttime.inSeconds.toDouble() : 0.0,
```